# Is a Cauchy sequence in R necessarily a Cauchy sequence in Q

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in the metric space $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean metric, with the property that $x_n\in\mathbb{Q}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Is it true that $(x_n)$ in the metric space $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$ (and it's induced metric) is Cauchy?

Is this trivial or is there something substantial to prove?

The backstory behind this question is to prove a sequence is Cauchy in $\mathbb{Q}$. The sequence of rational numbers converges to an irrational number in $\mathbb{R}$, hence is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$, hence is Cauchy in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Yes, it follows directly. Cauchyness only depends on the pairwise distances $d(x_n, x_m)$, so it doesn't change when you restrict to a subspace with the induced metric.